# Let CMake setup CTtest to print header and footer around the output from single tests

Tags: cmake, ctest

Is there a way, ideally from `CMakeLists.txt`, to setup `ctest` as to

- print a header before running the individual tests,
- print a footer after running the individual tests,
- make the footer dependent on whether the tests were all successful or not ?

The footer should appear below the default output

```
The following tests FAILED:
       76 - MyHardTest
Errors while running CTest
```

This concretizes and generalizes a somewhat unclear question that is open since more than 2 years ([CMakeLists.txt: How to print a message if ctest fails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36629644/)). Therefore I fear there is no easy solution.

Thence an alternative question: could the desired bevhavior achieved with `CDash`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

YES, CTest does have macros to achieve exactly this [1]:

- `CTEST_CUSTOM_PRE_TEST` Command to execute before any tests are run during Test stage
- `CTEST_CUSTOM_POST_TEST` Command to execute after any tests are run during Test stage

To activate these macros from `cmake` for use by `ctest`, they must somehow be placed into the *build* directory. So it seems, two steps are necessary:

(1) Have a script `scriptdir/CTestCustom.cmake.in` somewhere in the source tree, which contains

```
set(CTEST_CUSTOM_POST_TEST "echo AFTER_THE_TEST")
```

or whatever whatever command instead of "echo"

(2) Let `CMakeLists.txt` call

```
configure_file("scriptdir/CTestCustom.cmake.in" ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/CTestCustom.cmake)
```

so that during configuration stage a CTest configuration file is placed under the preferred name [2] `CTestCustom.cmake` in the *build* directory.

[1] https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Testing_With_CTest
[2] https://blog.kitware.com/ctest-performance-tip-use-ctestcustom-cmake-not-ctest/

Answer (score 0):

During my research, I found it was extremely difficult to integrate something like this. I am not entirely sure but I believe you can do this in CTestScript, then create a `add_custom_target` to always allow that Script to execute with `ctest`. For example, the command `make check` will now run `ctest` with the CTestScript that you made... too much work?

Easiest way I can think of for your application is to just add two empty tests at top and bottom as placeholders for header and footers. Ctest already has a "The following tests FAILED:" kind of output at the very end, so you might not have to worry about it. Any sort of conditional logic `IF TEST FAILED DO THIS`, you cannot do currently in ctest.

```
add_test(NAME HEADER_GOES_HERE)
add_test(NAME ACTUAL_TEST COMMAND test)
add_test(NAME FOOTER_GOES_HERE)
```

Maybe someone can give you a better answer, but this is the easiest (not at all good) implementation I can think of.